# Implementing redundant GIT backup scheme

Tags: git, shell, bash

I want to push a local repo to multiple remote GIT repositories to achieve redundancy in my backup scheme. So, let's say I plan to use Github and BitBucket to host my repositories.

I have two questions.

1. Is this approach advisable?
2. If so, how should I best approach writing a shell script to automate my backup procedures? For example, would I need to change my repo identity in the shell script for every backup operation or does a set of commands exist that will make this process easier?

Comment: Do you even need a shell script? Just use `git push`

Comment: @immibis: My question regards that I will have multiple repos. So are you saying the best approach would be to manually change the repo destination prior to each `git push` command? What if I have more than two repos for redundancy? I was hoping there might be a way to submit a list of target repos that can be "shotgun blasted" with a single `git push` command for the purposes of redundancy.

Comment: `git push origin master; git push backup master` would work, if your two remotes are called `origin` and `backup` for example.

Comment: Don't you trust Github or BitBucket enough in their ability to make regular backups of their servers? :-)

Comment: You can probably use git hooks to push to other remotes after having pushed to e.g. origin

Comment: @DocBrown Can you get GitHub/Bitbucket to restore your repository to a previous state when you manage to irrecoverably ruin parts of it? Backups for the purpose of unscrewing legitimate changes are distinct from resilient storage that happily takes any change you throw at it.

Comment: @LarsViklund: well, I have not much experience with GitHub or Bitbucket, but is that really a serious risk one has to deal with? And if you manage to  irrecoverably ruin parts of your repo by legitimate git commands, making a synced backup to two different providers won't bring you much benefit, this just leaves you with two ruined repos.

Comment: @DocBrown Indeed, that's the point that I wanted to get through in some way, doing the same incorrect thing to multiple repositories just gets you more of the same breakage.

Comment: I personally would use a post-receive hook, and inside that have n push commands to n redundant repos